# why my program to this factorial problem does not work?

Tags: python-3.x, list, integer, numbers, factorial

i need to make a program like so:
you need to have inputs, a0, n, d by order. (while a0 and n >= 0 , d > 0)
The program will print the value to the screen receives from n! while the product will contain only product values ​​whose place in the series (a0, a0+1,....n) divided by d without remnant (%d)
information and integers between Factors that are smaller than a0 will not be included in the hem of the factorial.
if there are no integers between a0 to n the program will print the value of 0! such is 1.

for example:
a0= 2, n= 6, d=3 ---> the program will print 18
(we remove from 6! the numbers under a0 and the number that are not %d)

```
a0 = int(input())
n = int(input())
d = int(input())
sol = 1
res = [int(x+1) for x in range(n)]
for i in range(len(res)):
    if i >= a0:
        if i % d == 0:
            sol = a0 * res[i] * sol

print(sol)
```

like in the exaple, a0=2, n=6, d=3
the program print 4, and i expect to get 18

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. What is it outputting now/ what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work the best for you:

```
def factorial(a0, n, d):
    if a0 < 0 or n < 0 or d < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        result = 1
        for i in range(a0, n+1):
            if i % d == 0:
                result *= i
        return result

print(factorial(2, 6, 3))
```

Comment: thank you! it helped a lot and i managed to do it without def, but i got the inspiration from you :)